# TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.investing.com/crypto/currencies")
elem = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'table')

head = elem.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'thead')
body = elem.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'tbody')

list_rows = []

for items in body.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'tr'):
    list_cells = []
    for item in items.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'td'):
        list_cells.append(item.text)
    list_rows.append(list_cells)
driver.close()
```

**Output**
for items in body.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'tr'):
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

I want to scrape a table from website by selenium and pandas.
But I have get some error in my for loop.
please any expert solve this problem.
please give me a write code that I can use to scrape data from table in any webpage.

**MY error is down blow**
for items in body.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'tr'):
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Comment: Maybe I could help with your new question too, but since you not following stackoverflow instructions I will not, I'm sorry. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

`find_element` returns a single web element object while you need to get a list of web element objects. `find_elements` does this.
So, you need to change form `find_element` to `find_elements` so it will be:

```py
for items in body.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'tr'):
    list_cells = []
    for item in items.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'td'):
        list_cells.append(item.text)
    list_rows.append(list_cells)
```